# Prediction done on tf-idf array, how to merge with original data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tf-idf

I have text data, pandas data frame, which, i converted in to tf-idf vectors than using ML algorithm prediction done.so, how to merge results of xtest on indexes with xtest pandas data frame. I have performed train_test_split after on word embedding, not on pandas data frame.
when i check:

```
array.index()
Numpy array has no attribute index
```

Shape of array is (3480,5000),when i try below code:

```
len(array.indices)
10480
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) for clarity

Answer (score 0):

assuming that pred is your predictions

it's numpy array, then you can df.merge preds as Series to main df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1, 2, 3, 4])


pred = np.array([0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.11])

series = pd.Series(pred, index=df.index, name='C')
result = df.merge(series, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(result)
```

Comment: Actually, i want to merge with original text data frame, which has been converted to tfidf vectors, before train_test_splt performed. So i want to extract test part of original data frame first on the bases of from tfidf vectors  index, then i can directly assign predictions

Comment: i think you need split your data idx_train, idx_test = train_test_split(df.index, random_state=42), because if you split it after you create leakage of test data into train data